# How to obtain list of Installed Packages loadable by Get (<<)

Tags: packages, built-in-symbols, paclets

When `` Get["MyPackage`"] `` is executed, *Mathematica* looks for a package in `$UserBaseDirectory`/Applications, and it does, it will load it.

Is there a Mathematica function that lists the installed packages installed in `$UserBaseDirectory`/Applications that are loadable by `Get`?

For example, is there something like `InstalledApplications[]` which returns `` {"MyPackage`", "OtherPackage`", ...} ``?

Comment: Not sure if it's better to ask a separate question… but how about making the goal of this question higher? In _Maple_ packages can be loaded or unloaded through menu. Can we have something similar in _Mathematica_? : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yztaE.png

Comment: @xzczd if my paclet server (https://paclets.github.io/PacletServer/) takes off it'd be possible to cook in. I could also write up a palette for doing that with Wolfram's built-in paclets too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing truly built in, but this is easy to roll if you know how to work with paclets. `PacletInformation` will return a `"Context"` parameter that specifies contexts for that paclet that may be loaded by `Get`. `PacletFind[]` will return all paclets. So then just attach the `".m"` and `".wl"` files and you get:

```
Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Join[
   FileBaseName[#] <> "`" & /@ 
    FileNames[WordCharacter .. ~~ (".m" | ".wl"), $Path],
   Select[
    Flatten@Lookup[PacletInformation /@ PacletFind[], "Context"],
    StringMatchQ[(WordCharacter | "`") ..]
    ]
   ]

{"Alexa`", "AmhCode`", "AnatomyGraphics3D`", \
"AnatomyGraphics3DLoader`", "ArduinoCompile`", "ArduinoLink`", \
"ArduinoUpload`", "Arxiv`", "ArXivLoad`", \
"AstronomyConvenienceFunctions`", \
"AstronomyConvenienceFunctionsLoader`", "AuthDialogs`", \
"Authentication`", "AVRCCompiler`", "AWSLink`", "Benchmarking`", \
"BingSearch`", "BingSearchFunctions`", "BingSearchLoad`", \
"BlockBuilder`", "BTools`", "CacheManager`", "CCodeGenerator`", \
"CCompilerDriver`", "ChannelFramework`", "ChannelFrameworkLoader`", \
"ChatSystem`", "ChatTools`", "ChatToolsLoader`", "ChemSpider`", \
"ChemSpiderLoad`", "ChemTools`", "CloudExpression`", \
"CloudExpressionLoader`", "CloudObject`", "CloudObjectLoader`", \
"CodeSeal`", "CodeSeal`Authoring`", "CompiledFunctionTools`", \
"CompoundMatrixMethod`", "CoursewareTools`", "CrossRef`", \
"CrossRefLoad`", "Cryptography`", "CUDALink`", "CURLLink`", \
"DAALLink`", "Databases`", "DataDropClient`", \
"DataDropClientLoader`", "DataResource`", "DataResourceLoader`", \
"Dataset`", "DatasetLoader`", "DemoChannels`Oneliner`", \
"DemoChannels`WIM`", "Developer`", "DeviceFramework`Devices`", \
"DocFind`", "DocGen`", "DocumentationBuild`", "Dropbox`", \
"DynamicWebImage`", "EmbedCode`", "EmbedCodeLoader`", \
"EmbeddedService`", "EmbeddedServiceLoader`", "EncodedCache`", \
"EntityFramework`", "EntityFrameworkLoader`", "ExcelUpdate`", \
"ExceptionHandling`", "Experimental`", "ExtendedTools`", \
"ExternalEvaluate`", "ExternalEvaluateLoader`", \
"ExternalEvaluatePython`", "Facebook`", "FacebookLoad`", "Factual`", \
"FactualFunctions`", "FactualLoad`", "FDLLink`", \
"FederalReserveEconomicData`", "FederalReserveEconomicDataLoad`", \
"FEInfoExtractor`", "FETools`", "FileBrowser`", "Firmata`", \
"Fitbit`", "FitbitFunctions`", "FitbitLoad`", "Flickr`", \
"FlickrLoad`", "Forms`", "FormsLoader`", "FormulaData`", \
"FormulaDataLoader`", "FrontEndGraphics`", "GeneralUtilities`", \
"GeneralUtilitiesLoader`", "GeoFieldModelData`", \
"GeoFieldModelDataLoader`", "GitBookBuilder`", "GitConnection`", \
"GoogleAnalytics`", "GoogleAnalyticsLoad`", "GoogleCalendar`", \
"GoogleCalendarLoad`", "GoogleContacts`", "GoogleContactsLoad`", \
"GoogleCustomSearch`", "GoogleCustomSearchFunctions`", \
"GoogleCustomSearchLoad`", "GooglePlus`", "GooglePlusLoad`", \
"GoogleTranslate`", "GoogleTranslateFunctions`", \
"GoogleTranslateLoad`", "GPUTools`", "HDF5Tools`", "HTTPClient`", \
"HTTPHandling`", "HTTPLink`", "HTTPLinkLoader`", "HTTPListen`", \
"HumanGrowthData`", "HumanGrowthDataLoader`", "Iconize`", \
"IconizeLoader`", "IGraphM`", "IMAPLink`", "IMAPLinkLoader`", \
"InflationAdjust`", "InflationAdjustLoader`", "init`", "Instagram`", \
"InstagramLoad`", "IntegratedServices`", "IntegratedServicesLoader`", \
"Interpreter`", "IPOPTLink`", "JavaGraphics`", "JLink`", \
"JSONStream`", "LightGBMLink`", "LinearAlgebra`", "LinkedIn`", \
"LinkedInLoad`", "MachineLearning`", "MachineLearningLoader`", \
"Macros`", "MacrosLoader`", "MailChimp`", "MailChimpLoad`", \
"MailLink`", "MailLinkLoader`", "MaTeX`", \
"MathematicalFunctionData`", "MathematicalFunctionDataLoader`", \
"MicrosoftTranslator`", "MicrosoftTranslatorFunctions`", \
"MicrosoftTranslatorLoad`", "MiscFuncs`", "Mixpanel`", \
"MixpanelFunctions`", "MixpanelLoad`", "MobileMessaging`", \
"MobileMessagingLoader`", "MoleculeViewer`", "MongoLink`", \
"MQTTLink`", "MSETools`", "MTools`", "MUnit`", "MUnitLoader`", \
"MXNetLink`", "MyProjects`", "NaturalLanguageProcessing`", \
"NaturalLanguageProcessingLoader`", "NDSolve`FEM`", "NETLink`", \
"NeuralFunctions`", "NeuralNetResource`", "NeuralNetworks`", \
"NotebookTabbing`", "NotebookToPackage`", "NumericArrayUtilities`", \
"OAuth`", "OAuthLoader`", "OAuthSigning`", "OldHelpBrowser`", \
"OpenCLLink`", "OpenLibrary`", "OpenLibraryFunctions`", \
"OpenLibraryLoad`", "OpenPHACTS`", "OpenPHACTSLoad`", \
"PackageDataPacletInstall`", "PacletManager`", "PaneFileBrowser`", \
"PLI`", "PLILoader`", "PredictiveInterface`", "PresenterTools`", \
"ProcessLink`", "ProcessLinkLoader`", "PubChem`", "PubChemLoad`", \
"PublicPacletServer`", "PubMed`", "PubMedLoad`", "Pushbullet`", \
"PushbulletAPIFunctions`", "PushbulletLoad`", "PyTools`", \
"QuantityUnits`", "QuantityUnitsLoader`", "Reddit`", \
"RedditFunctions`", "RedditLoad`", "ResizePane`", \
"ResourceSystemClient`", "ResourceSystemInternalTools`", \
"ResourceSystemInternalToolsLoader`", "RobotTools`", \
"RobotToolsLoader`", "RunKeeper`", "RunKeeperLoad`", \
"SearchBrowser`", "SeatGeek`", "SeatGeekLoad`", "SecureShellLink`", \
"SemanticImport`", "SemanticImportLoader`", "SETools`", \
"Sheepshead`", "SketchTemplate`", "SMTPLink`", "SMTPLinkLoader`", \
"SpellCorrect`", "SpellCorrectLoader`", "SpellingData`", \
"SpellingDataLoader`", "StandardOceanData`", \
"StandardOceanDataLoader`", "StoppingPowerData`", \
"StoppingPowerDataLoader`", "Streaming`", "StreamingLoader`", \
"StreamLink`", "StylesheetEdit`", "SurveyMonkey`", \
"SurveyMonkeyLoad`", "SymbolicMachineLearning`", \
"SymbolicMachineLearningLoader`", "SymbolObjects`", \
"SyntaxHighlighting`", "SystemInstall`", "SystemInstallLoader`", \
"SystemTest`", "SystemTools`", "Templating`", "Terminal`", \
"TestApp`", "TetGenLink`", "TextSearch`", "TextSearchLoader`", \
"TextTranslation`", "TextTranslationLoader`", "TINSLink`", \
"Transmogrify`", "TravelDirectionsClient`", \
"TravelDirectionsClientLoader`", "TriangleLink`", "Twilio`", \
"TwilioFunctions`", "TwilioLoad`", "TwilioSendMessage`", "Twitter`", \
"TwitterFunctions`", "TwitterLoad`", "TypeSystem`", \
"TypeSystemLoader`", "URLUtilities`", "UWTools`", "VernierLink`", \
"WebSearch`", "WebSearchLoader`", "WebUnit`", "WebUnit`Utilities`", \
"WebUnit`WebDriverAPI`", "Wikipedia`", "WikipediaData`", \
"WikipediaDataLoader`", "WikipediaFunctions`", "WikipediaLoad`", \
"WolframAlphaClient`", "WolframBlockchain`", \
"WolframBlockchainLoader`", "WolframScript`", "WordFrequency`", \
"WordFrequencyLoader`", "WSM`", "WSMLink`", "WSMLoader`", "Yelp`", \
"YelpFunctions`", "YelpLoad`", "ZeroMQLink`", "ZeroMQLinkLoader`"}
```

Comment: ``"DatabaseLink`"`` is oddly missing.

Comment: @Edmund that may be a holdover from when I used it in v10. It could have installed the paclet then but been removed in v11. This obviously reflects the state of my machine only.

Answer (score 6):

There is no foolproof way to do this. Packages may be installed in very different ways.  The other answer talks about paclets.  Here's something for non-paclet packages.

```
candidates = Catenate[
   Function[path,
     FileNameTake[#] <> "`" & /@ 
      Select[FileNames[All, path], DirectoryQ]
     ] /@ $Path
   ];

Select[candidates, FindFile[#] =!= $Failed &]
```

This enumerates all directories within paths contained in `$Path`. Then it appends a backtick to turn them into context names.  If [`FindFile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFile.html) can resolve a context name to a loadable file, it is kept. Otherwise, it is thrown out.

It *does* give false positives that are not packages, but to be fair, these false positives *are* in face loadable with `` <<name` ``, even if they are not meant to.

It also misses packages which are loadable by `` <<name`subname` ``.